# How to run exec command in a loop until it is successful

Tags: bash, docker, redhat-enterprise-linux, exec

I want run exec $Docker-run command until it's successful on redhat linux. Looping over it?

```
$Docker-run = docker run --env-file .env Image-name
```

Can anyone provide a solution?

Comment: when you say "until it is successful" what does that mean precisely? will the executable return 0 on success and somthing else on failure? if so, you could look at the `until` keyword.

Comment: I am gonna do something like this :
`until docker run --env-file .env Image-name
do
        echo ...
        sleep 1
done`

Comment: And what happened when you did that, what errors did you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

A simple while loop and conditional statement could do this for you.

For example

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CONTAINER_SUCCESS=0
while [ $CONTAINER_SUCCESS -ne 1 ]; do
  docker run --rm alpine uname -a
  CONTAINER_EXIT=$?
  if [ $CONTAINER_EXIT -eq 0 ]; then
    CONTAINER_SUCCESS=1
  fi
done
```

When running `uname -a`, the exit code was `0`, and the script did not loop. When running `failure`, there was no binary that matched this, and the run command kept executing.

This does assume that your success state is `0`, but can be edited to suit your needs.